# EntityFramework 4.5 - Still get ObjectDisposedException even after using Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am facing the exception **The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection** even after using the Include method.

Here the function that retrieve the entities:

```
    public List<Entity.CapacityGrid> SelectByFormula(string strFormula, int iVersionId)
    {
        // declaration
        List<Entity.CapacityGrid> oList;

        // retrieve ingredients
        oList = (from Grid in _Dc.CapacityGrid.Include("EquipmentSection")
                             join Header in _Dc.CapacityHeader
                             on Grid.HeaderId equals Header.HeaderId
                             where Header.Formula == strFormula
                             && Header.VersionId == iVersionId
                             select Grid).ToList();

        // return
        return oList;
```

Here the usage of the function:

```
        // retrieve ingredient quantity by equipement
        using (Model.CapacityGrid oModel = new Model.CapacityGrid(Configuration.RemoteDatabase))
            oQuantity = oModel.SelectByFormula(strFormulaName, iVersionId);

        // code to throw the exception
        var o = (oQuantity[0].EquipmentSection.TypeId);
```

I understand that the using is closing the connection. I thought the ToList() will instantiated the list of objects and the related objects in the include before closing.

> Can someone point me out what I do wrong?
>   Sorry, my question was not clear. I do understand that including the line that throw exception inside the bracket of the using is working, but I do not figure out **why does the include does not works**?

Thank you!

Comment: Try the `.Include` just before the `ToList`, like this: `.Include(g => g.Equipmentsection).ToList()`

Comment: Hello DavidG, somehow, there is no include function. I wrote the line and I get the message: System.Linq.IQueryable<Entity.CapacityGrid>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type. Thanks!

Comment: I assume that `_Dc.CapacityGrid` is a `DbSet`? If so, it is true that the Include should work. Did you check out the generated SQL?

Comment: @SebastienDErrico : Have you included the System.Data.Entity namespace ? This is where the `Include` extension method is set.

Comment: You are right gretro, I missed the using for System.Data.Entity

Comment: Thank you guys, the include works. What is the differnce between putting the include in the from (where it throw an exception in my case) and the include before the ToList (where everything works fine) ?

Comment: DavidG, because moving the include is working as you suggested, do you want to propose it as an answer? I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three solutions to your problem. These come from this link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj574232.aspx) and are the three ways to link to a Related Entity. The first solution is the Lazy loading solution, that you have been using. Just modify your code to this and it will work. The reason why it was throwing an exception is because lazy loading occurs only when you need it. It's a great solution when you need to load the related entities only on a few entities.

```
// retrieve ingredient quantity by equipement
using (Model.CapacityGrid oModel = new Model.CapacityGrid(Configuration.RemoteDatabase))
{
    oQuantity = oModel.SelectByFormula(strFormulaName, iVersionId);

    // Lazy-load occurs here, so it needs to have access to the
    // context, hence why it is in the using statement.
    var o = (oQuantity.First().EquipmentSection.TypeId);
}
```

The second solution is to use eager-loading (as suggested by @DavidG). Because you only load the related entity of the first entity found, I do not recommend you use this in your case because it will load the EquipmentSection entity of all your oQuantity entities. In your `SelectByFormula` method, use an Include statement as shown in the related link and it will load it on the first call (it will not duplicate the access to the database, but it will pull more data at once).

The third solution is to avoid relying on Lazy Loading, and can be a good way to go to. It's the Explicit loading technique, which will require you to specify that you want to load the `EquipmentSection` related entity on the specified entity.

I hope those explanations help you.

Also, you might want to consider returning an IQueryable on your `SelectByFormula` method. This way, if you have to filter requests, like with the `First()` method to obtain only the first occurance, you are not pulling everything only for one instance.

Comment: Nice answer, but I disagree with your statement to not use eager loading. In most situations lazy loading doesn't give you any added benefit, and in fact can make your application slower. Anyway, +1 from me.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in the answer. I specified that I would not use it in this case because he loads all entities corresponding to a formula then only takes the value of the related entity of the first item. In this case, Eager loading will probably just load much more data than Lazy loading or Explicit loading. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Adding the System.Data.Entity and moving the include before the .ToList like is shown in the link solved my problem without moving the bracked of the using clause. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
    // retrieve ingredient quantity by equipement
    using (Model.CapacityGrid oModel = new Model.CapacityGrid(Configuration.RemoteDatabase))
   {  // <-- **add these**
        oQuantity = oModel.SelectByFormula(strFormulaName, iVersionId);

    // code to throw the exception
    var o = (oQuantity[0].EquipmentSection.TypeId);
   } // <-- **add these**
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

With no `{}` to englobe the using, the connection is disposed right after the first line. Because Entity framework uses Expression trees (this means that the request is not executed until it really needs it), your query happens at `var o = (oQuantity[0].EquipmentSection.TypeId);`.

Comment: Should also put the oQuantity in the using statement.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: How does it not- "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection". The object was being disposed- enclosing the code with the proper braces will eliminate that problem.

Comment: No, the question is why the Include doesn't do what it apparently should do. Not how to fix it.

Comment: in the question I am failing to see how this is not answer- please elaborate. The object oModel is disposed- as soon as it's disposed trying to do anything with it will throw that exception. Wrapping it in the braces will eliminate that problem, and if the .Include() still has issues they will be new- and a different question. Am I missing something?

Comment: Both solutions are good. By extending the using statement, we use Lazy loading, which results in a second query to the database. The solution @DavidG proposes is also valid and is known as eager loading, which will result as only one query to the database. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: I do understand that including the line that throw exception inside the bracket of the using is working, but I do not figure out why does the include does not works?

Comment: @SebastienDErrico Not sure- for the question asked that is the answer- for your new question, that is a LINQ question. You should have different errors, and with that correction, you should now be able to break and step through and see what is executing