# Entity Framework tries to lazy load the object again when it is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem about the way entity framework handle null objects.
Below example is a simple 1 to 0..1 relationship.  When the Profile doesn't exist for a person, the Profile object under Person object is null.

But EF is trying to do a lazy loading fetch again.  As a result, **ObjectDisposedException** is throw.

```
public void Test()
{
    Person person = null;

    using (var ctx = new MainContext())
    {
        person = ctx.Persons
            .Include(c => c.Profile);
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Ben");
    }

    // ObjectDisposedException is throw here if Profile doesn't exist
    var profile = person.Profile;
}
```

It seems like EF can't distinguish between 'doesn't exist' and 'not fetch yet'.  The best solution I have now is to disable lazy loading.

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

But that will hide all the ObjectDisposedException I want to see cuz I may forget to put Include sometimes, and now they all become null.

Any better idea for handling this?

Comment: What happens if you do `.Include(..).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault()` ?

Comment: Yes, AsNoTracking() did the trick!  Thanks SimpleVar!

Comment: When laziness over weighs rep

Answer (score 0):

Do a left outer join, this will return all persons regardless of whether they have profiles or not.

```
var query = (from p in ctx.Persons
                join pr in ctx.Profiles on p equals pr.PersonId into gj
                from subpr in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where p.Name == "Ben"
                select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

[More about this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb397895.aspx)

Comment: My problem is not about Person being returned or not.  But the Profile under the Person instance is null.

Answer (score 0):

If you just processing the null object,you can initialize the object in class constructor,like this:

```
public Person
{
    this.Profile = new Profile();
}
```

Comment: I can't create the object on my own.  The data is retrieved and the instance is created by the EF framework.  

The Profile object can be null, or may not be null.  So I just can't create the instance by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it was throwing an exception is because lazy loading occurs only when you need it and not when you are doing an include.

When you are telling your code that you "need" profile outside your using, so there's no more context for EF to fetch the data and you receive the error.

Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj574232.aspx)
or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457738/entityframework-4-5-still-get-objectdisposedexception-even-after-using-include).

Your code should work if you do:

```
public void Test()
{
    Person person = null;

    using (var ctx = new MainContext())
    {
        person = ctx.Persons
            .Include(c => c.Profile);
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Ben");
            // code inside the using
            var profile = person.Profile;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand that putting the last code inside the using will work.  But this is not feasible because Profile will be invoked somewhere else.

I am looking for a way to avoid the lazy loading in this situation.  In fact, it should be doing eager loading when I put the Include statement.  Why is it doing lazy loading again when the value is null?